# Wrapping a Node as children cannot fire the function

Tags: reactjs

So I have this code

```
<bar change={this.change.bind(this)} />
```

which is working properly but when I wrap bar:

```
<foo children={<bar change={this.change.bind(this)}/>} />
```

change function is not triggered anymore. Any thoughts about this?

Comment: Can you show mode code of the foo component and also to wrap as children you should ideally specify the elements within tags

Comment: bar contains the 'change' function, and is a children from foo. now when i tried to trigger the 'change' function from bar, it does not get triggered. The only difference is put bar as a child.

Comment: Please provide working example, on jsFiddle or plunkr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change function is triggered. problem must be from something else. maybe a HOC is interrupting.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  change(){
    alert('this code is running in ' + this.constructor.name + ' component');
  }

  render() {
    return <Foo children={<Bar change={this.change.bind(this)} />} />;
  }
}

class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}

class Bar extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.props.change}>This is Bar component, click me to run change method!</div>;
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this , I was actually using a material-ui Autocomplete and I just replicated the code. I found the problem and yes you are correct :)